# Is there a way to force Webview to login to Facebook using the native iOS 6 Facebook Credentials

Tags: facebook, ios6, uiwebview, facebook-social-plugins, social-framework

I have a question regarding the facebook Comments using social Plugin on iOS6. I use social Framework to login into my app using facebook credentials set in the phone settings. Facebook loads the comments on a UIWebview inside one of the screen in my app. But inorder to post comments it asks me to login again whereas I  already logged in using Social Framework. I do not want to login again on Webview. Is there a way to force Webview to login to Facebook using the native iOS 6 Facebook Credentials.

Comment: I am looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

After Configuring facebook in your phone setting ,use ACAccount framework to request access to facebook account with required permissions  prams and then either you can use  SLComposeViewController: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205 class (to use default post UI View) or Can use SLRequest (using graph api URL post) to post on your wall.